# How can protect the Asp.Net MVC 5 in the Edit action route from throwing unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a standard Edit action in Asp.Net MVC 5 and I want to avoid throwing the unhandled exception when a get request is made without the id like `~/food/edit`, so I did this.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        string result = _foodAppService.GetById(id);
        FoodVm food = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) 
            ? null 
            : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FoodVm>(result);

        if (food == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(food);
    }
```

My question is: Is it a good practice to handled it in this way or there are more suitable strategies ?

I'm new to this asking question thing, if a should I ask in another way, just let me know, thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that any answer will inevitably be opinionated, and that's outside the scope of Stack Overflow. You might want to take the question over to Code Review, instead.

Comment: you could create an action filter and then just apply it to the methods you want. You also don't need to initalize the int to 0.  int's automatically get initialized to 0.  How could you get to this situation in the first place?  aren't you creating the edit links?  are you worried about people just typing in gibberish?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I didn't know that there was such thing, I just post it there, thank you, as I said:  I'm new to this asking thing.

Comment: @Fran, yes. I'm worried about security. I don't want people tweaking the urls.

Comment: "yes. I'm worried about security. I don't want people tweaking the urls" - not something you can really prevent. I can post/get to any url I can imagine. You need to validate the user and/or inputs which is what you are getting at here.

Comment: Never trust the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case zero could be valid its better to do

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or there can be more overall way to handle exceptions in MVC. You can use override of method `OnException` this gives you abbility to debug all exception in controllers in one method and handle them.
Just add base class to all your controllers like this:

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
 {
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        string redirectUrl;
        var exception = filterContext.Exception;

        if (exception is EntityException)
        {
            redirectUrl = "/Content/error.html";
        }
        else
        {
            redirectUrl = "/Info/Index";
        }

        //do whatever you wont

        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
```

Also use input parameters verification as Paul Swetz saied. This method is more genera, allows to intercept all exceptions, and don`t show errors to users.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Fran 's advice. I built a action filter attribute called `MissingParam`

```
public class MissingParamAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public string ParamName { get; set; }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey(ParamName))
      {
         if (filterContext.ActionParameters[ParamName] == null)
         {
            filterContext.ActionParameters[ParamName] = 0;
         }
      }

   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
}
```

in the action I did this:

```
[MissingParam(ParamName="id")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

That way I don't need to mess with method parameter, any validating happens before. This implementation follows the Open/Close principle. I extended its functionality, but I didn't changed like the code in the question.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost its a good practice to use Try-Catch.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
 {
     try
     {
            if (id != 0 || id!=null)
           {
            string result = _foodAppService.GetById(id);
            FoodVm food = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? null:JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FoodVm>(result);

            if (food == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {    
            return View(food);
            }
          }
         else
          {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
          }
    }
    catch (exception ex)
    {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, **DONT** use try catch if you really don`t need it. It`s really slow and done your code really dirty.
Read pls:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Adding on, your try/catch block covers code that will never throw exceptions. It isn't a good practice to put everything you write into a try/catch block. Treat exceptions like exceptional situations (which is what they ought to be).

Comment: if you going to fetch data from the database, Having a try catch is life saver. you never know something would go wrong in the DB. It also helps to have a logger that will keep track of error log.

Comment: no.  smattering try/catches all around your code is not a good practice.  If you are only looking to log, add a global exception handler or add elmah to your project.